# Why is this Chart.js graph not showing the right colors?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to show a bar graph from two datasets for every month to show the evolution of certain data. Now the problem is the way Chart.js is showing these bars.

[image: Graph]

```
var myChartIBM = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Número de entregas",
            data: entregas,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: "Número de reversas",
            data: reversas,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 500
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        distribution: 'series',
                        offset: true,
                        ticks: {
                            source: 'data'
                        },
                        time: {
                            unit: 'month',
                            tooltipFormat: 'll'
                        }
                    }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'x', // optional
            callbacks: {
              title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                let tI = tooltipItems[0];
                return data.datasets[tI.datasetIndex].data[tI.index].x;
              }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                        return value['y'];
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true
    }
});
```

My doubt is why is it showing grey after the first dataset and what could I do to fix this. Maybe should I always add a zero?

This is the code on PHP side which generates the data:

```
$col_entregas = Device::select(DB::raw("count(serial) as cantidad, year(fecha_recepcion) as year, month(fecha_recepcion) as month"))->whereNotNull('fecha_recepcion')->whereNotNull('guia_recepcion')->groupBy('year', 'month')->orderBy('year', 'asc')->orderBy('month', 'asc')->get();
    $col_reversas = Device::select(DB::raw("count(serial) as cantidad, year(fecha_reversa) as year, month(fecha_reversa) as month"))->whereNotNull('fecha_reversa')->whereNotNull('guia_reversa')->groupBy('year', 'month')->orderBy('year', 'asc')->orderBy('month', 'asc')->get();

    $ar_entregas = [];
    $ar_reversas = [];
    $meses_grafico =  [];
    foreach($col_entregas as $entrega)
    {
        $fecha = $entrega->year . '-' . $entrega->month;
        $meses_grafico[] = $fecha;
        $ar_entregas[] = ["x" => $fecha,
                          "y" => $entrega->cantidad];
    }
    foreach($col_reversas as $reversa)
    {
        $fecha = $reversa->year . '-' . $reversa->month;
        $ar_reversas[] = [
            "x" => $fecha,
            "y" => $reversa->cantidad];
    }
```

Comment: I think you need a color for each bar; that is, a color value for each entry in the `data` arrays.

Comment: I believe you need a background color for each item in the corresponding data array. see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html for example

Comment: I mean there are two datasets and the docs don't clarify very well how it expects colors to be set up.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to add a foreach to add the same color to every entry in both arrays and that fixed the issue:

[image: Fixed issue]

```
var colors_entregas = [];
var border_entregas = [];
entregas.forEach(function (el){
    colors_entregas.push('rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)');
    border_entregas.push('rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)');
});
var colors_reversas = [];
var border_reversas = [];

reversas.forEach(function (el){
    colors_reversas.push('rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)');
    border_reversas.push('rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)');
});
```

Inside every dataset:

```
data: entregas,
backgroundColor: colors_entregas,
borderColor: border_entregas,
```